# Outlook Rule for not being in a mail group

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter, rules

Can I create an outlook rule to filter mail if it is sent directly to my email address (and any others) as opposed to being sent to a mail group that I belong to?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t found such a condition to filter email sent directly to your email address. But we can create a search folder to realize this. To do this, click Folder > New Search Folder. Select “Mail sent directly to me” and click OK.

[image]